# Issue with evaluating ${error} in Spring

Tags: spring, jsp, jstl, el

I have defined an expression as ${error} in my jsp page , and when i am printing the value of the same using `<c:out value='${error}' />` , the output is `${error}`. Whereas the expression is not being evaluated.

I have included the jstl-1.2-api and jstl1.2-impl jar files in my lib directory , and also included the taglib `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>` in my JSP.

Can anybody please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that your `web.xml` is declared conform at least Servlet 2.5 spec and that your container also actually supports this. For example, Tomcat 6.x or newer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <!-- Config here. -->

</web-app>
```

You also need to ensure that the `/WEB-INF/lib` of the WAR is not cluttered with servletcontainer-specific libraries of an older version, such as `jsp-api.jar`, `el-api.jar`, etcetera.

Comment: Thanks a lottttttttt !!!!!! You have made my day, I spent almost 2 days on this, figuring out the issue.

My web.xml did for conform to the Servlet 2.5 spec, modified it, and it worked like a charm.

Thanks a ton once more... :)